# emacs org-mode clocktable - clock-in clock-out columns

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to configure the summary clocktable to have two extra columns for clock-in and clock-out times.

```
| Headline                                  | Clock-in | Clock-out | Time   |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+--------+------|
| *Total time*                              |          |           | *0:51* |      |
|-------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+--------+------|
```

Comment: This question would probably do better on StackOverflow.